# Improving my answer after it's been accepted

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If my answer is accepted and then someone else adds an answer that isn't as good but has a few points that I didn't have should I add those points to my answer? Feels like I would be stealing their ideas/work.

Comment: One option would be to add a footnote referencing the other answer and noting what else there is to read there.  Give credit where credit is due and nobody has any real ground to complain about it.

Comment: Agree with COTW, give credit. If it is a significant addition you may feel happier asking permission - I've done that before and most times it's met with a positive response. If you get no reply after a week or two you can take that as a 'yes'!

Comment: A good point noted James. You must first vote up his answer saying why you liked it and then as already stated say that you would be adding it in your answer JUST to make marked answer complete and at end of your answer give credit.